# How to update value of variable every minute to use it in another methods during app is running

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a method of time and it's set a one value when the application is running

```
  time()  {
      var hour =  TimeOfDay.now().hour;
      var minute =  TimeOfDay.now().minute;
      var doubleTime = hour + (minute / 60);
      return doubleTime;
  }
```

how I can make the value Update every minute .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Timer` of dart

```
  const oneMin= const Duration(minutes:1);
  Timer.periodic(oneMin, (Timer t) {
     time();
  });
```